# Copy all files from one folder to another and making them read only

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a bunch of boilerplate code that I copy to a number of projects using a windows batch script.

`xcopy /E/I/R/Y path\to\origin path\to\destination`

I want to set the read-only attribute on files copied to the destination folder as a reminder not to edit the file as it was generated automatically.  The destination folder will contain other code also, not just the code I copy from boilerplate.

I found the command to make a file read only, `attrib +r file.extension`,  how can I apply the read only attribute on each file copied to the destination folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "origin=originfolder"
set "destination=destinationfolder"
pushd %origin%
for %%a in ("*.*") do (
copy "%%a" "%destination%"
attrib +r "%destination%\%%a")
echo/Done.&pause>nul&exit/b
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do it in Windows 7 using robocopy.

`robocopy origin destination * /e /a+:R`